# How to find and remove control characters in a text file

Tags: c#, windows, unix, vbscript, batch-file

I've a .txt file which has control characters associated with email address.Some thing line this @ãgmail.com. There might be multiple instances of this and multiple instances of other control characters . Is there a way I can first find them and then remove them?

Comment: please specify the programming language or script language you want to use.

Comment: The file is around 400MB. I would be happy with C#, windows script or even Unix script

Comment: solution is: small c# programm, read file line by line, and use the Replace-Method of the string datatype to remove the unwanted chars. if you need source, it will last a few minutes.

Comment: Is it possible for us to have a regular expression to detect control characters?

Comment: as long as you are able to write regexp it is possible. if this is fast enough for a 400MB file - you should try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a piece of c# code - not very optimized for large count of control characters. a hint for starting:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"c:\temp.data\big_file_with_unwanted_chars.txt", Encoding.Default);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\temp.data\big_file_without_any_evil_chars.txt", false, Encoding.Default);

string al;

while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
  al = sr.ReadLine();
  al = al.Replace("ä", "");
  al = al.Replace("#", "");
  sw.WriteLine(al);
}
sw.Close();
sr.Close();
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a trick I picked up from [devdaily.com](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/linux-unix/how-remove-non-printable-ascii-characters-file-unix):

```
tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' < file-with-binary-chars > clean-file
```

This command deletes any character that is not a tab, line feed, carriage return, or in the range of printable ASCII characters (space through ~).

On Windows you can get the `tr` command from the [GNU Utilities for Win32](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) or [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).